# add images to bar button item of toolbar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to add images to bar button item of toolbar
i tried with xib and code both
but image shows up as white patch can anybody suggest what am i doing wrong
or which way should i proceed

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you added the image, preferably with code examples?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *bar = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:<#(UIImage *)image#> style:<#(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style#> target:<#(id)target#> action:<#(SEL)action#>];

Comment: i tried the above mentioned method and applied the image but white patch is always there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set the button type as custom.

Try like this

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(blah) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 32, 32)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

All the best.

Comment: isnt their any direct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

got a link which shows working like what Warrior suggests

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/33286-color-image-uibarbuttonitem-uitoolbar.html